# PDO::execute always returns FALSE but the query was succwssful

Tags: if-statement, pdo, sql-insert, execute

I'm trying to get a confirmation about saved row in DB, but my condition always returns FALSE.

```
$conn = new PDO($dir) or die("hovno");
$query = "INSERT INTO sncheck (caseId, snPaper, snBox, snUnit) VALUES ('$caseId', '$snPaper', '$snBox', '$snUnit')";
$prep = $conn->prepare($query);
if($prep->execute()){
    print "DONE";
}
else{
    print "ERROR";
}
```

It always triggers the `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Change to  this :

```
$req = $conn->prepare("INSERT sncheck users (caseId, snPaper, snBox, insnUnitos, roles_id) VALUES (:login, :password, :email, :infos, :snUnit)")or exit(print_r($conn->errorInfo()));
    $req->execute(array(
            "caseId" => $caseId, 
            "snPaper" => $snPaper,
            "snBox" => $snBox,
            "nUnit" => $nUnit
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to debug you query, as per below, so you will get the proper error message-

```
    $conn = new PDO($dir) or die("hovno");
    $query = "INSERT INTO sncheck (caseId, snPaper, snBox, snUnit) VALUES ('$caseId', '$snPaper', '$snBox', '$snUnit')";
    $prep = $conn->prepare($query);
    if (!$prep) {
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($conn->errorInfo());
    }

    if($prep->execute()){
        print "DONE";
    }else{
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($conn->errorInfo());
        print "ERROR";
    }
```

let me know if still have problem, with error message.

Comment: No error message. Just array: PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: @MélikZarkouna Tried it. It doesn't output anything error or not.

Comment: @MartinKellerII. so you need to debug the problem is not from the query